# Counting post meta based on key and value and get meta count, not post count

Tags: wordpress

I'm using WordPress meta data to register clicks on images, to know which images each user has clicked - and also the total number of clicked images per user. The first part is fine, but I'm struggling to get the counter going, as it's returning a lower amount of meta data than what is actually there.

I have a custom post type `gallerier` and each gallery has a number of images. I'm using the meta key `nedlasting`, and I'm identifying each image individually by fetching the url.

Here is how I register clicks, after checking it isn't already:

```
// Add meta query if it doesnt already exist
function sjekk_nedlasting( $postid, $url, $dato) {

    $brukerid = (string)get_current_user_id();

    // Check if the image is downloaded previously
    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'gallerier',
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => 'nedlasting',
               'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', $url),
               'compare' => 'LIKE'
           ),
           array(
               'key' => 'nedlasting',
               'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', $brukerid),
               'compare' => 'LIKE'
           )
       ),
       'fields' => 'ids'
    );
    // Perform the query
    $nedl_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $nedl_ids = $nedl_query->posts;

    // If not already downloaded, register it
    if ( empty( $nedl_ids ) ) {

    $metaarray = Array(
        'user_id' => $brukerid,
        'url' => $url,
        'date' => $dato
    );

        add_post_meta( $postid, 'nedlasting', $metaarray );
    }
}
```

Then I'm trying to count those registered clicks using the following function:

```
// Count number of downloads for a single user
function tell_nedlastinger() {

    $brukerid = (string)get_current_user_id();

    $args = array(
       'post_type' => 'gallerier',
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => 'nedlasting',
               'value' => sprintf(':"%s";', $brukerid),
               'compare' => 'LIKE'
           )
       ),
       'fields' => 'ids'
    );
    // perform the query
    $nedl_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    $nedl_ids = $nedl_query->posts;

    return count($nedl_ids);
}
```

The function returns a number, but always much lower than the actual amount of registered meta data/clicks. Anyone seeing a problem?

**Edit:** I'm pretty sure the problem is that I'm getting the total number of posts, not the total number of meta data entries/clicks - which more often that not is several per post. Any way around that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found a solution to query meta data and get x results per post, so instead of using an array in a single key I split the post meta data into three keys. Then I used $wpdb for a custom query. The final code for the tell_nedlastinger() function:

```
$brukerid = (string)get_current_user_id();

global $wpdb;
$query = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_postmeta WHERE (meta_key = 'nedlasting_brukerid' AND meta_value = '$brukerid')");

return count($query);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can improve the speed of this by using:

```
$brukerid = (string)get_current_user_id();

global $wpdb;
$count = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT COUNT(*) AS THE_COUNT FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE (meta_key = 'nedlasting_brukerid' AND meta_value = '$brukerid')");

return $count->THE_COUNT;
```

The speed is improved by only having to fetch one row from the database. Also note the use of:

```
FROM $wpdb->postmeta
```

This allows for a variable table prefix instead of assuming a table wp_ prefix.

Answer (score 0):

$metaCount = count( get_comment_meta($postId,'key','value') );

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).